# Jackson JSON: Serialize Array of Objects as their parent type

Tags: java, json, jackson, fasterxml

I'm serializing an array of objects of different types, but all of which are of supertype `BasicClass`. When I serialize it as such:

```
@JsonProperty
public BasicClass[] getReferences() {
    return this.refs;
}
```

it also serializes all the subtype JSON properties. How can I make it only serialize the supertype properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `@JsonSerialize` annotation. It will allow you to specify a `Typing` value as either `dynamic` or `static`. In your case you want to use the `static` type rather than waiting til runtime for it to see the specific subclass.

Comment: I would think that this would work, but it is still serializing JsonProperties that are only declared in the subclasses

Comment: What version of Jackson are you using?